# Eclipse PHP broken on fresh Ubuntu install

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 in a totally fresh virtual machine.

The first thing I did was install Eclipse, then the only plugin which I installed was Programming languages/PHP.

I created a new project and tried to add anew PHP file, which resulted in

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/util/StringTokenizer
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.utils.StringUtils.unpack(StringUtils.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.ExtendedConfigurationBuilder.createConfigurations(ExtendedConfigurationBuilder.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.ExtendedConfigurationBuilder.getConfigurations(ExtendedConfigurationBuilder.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.ExtendedConfigurationBuilder.getConfiguration(ExtendedConfigurationBuilder.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.createSourceViewerConfiguration(StructuredTextEditor.java:1678)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.updateSourceViewerConfiguration(StructuredTextEditor.java:3438)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.update(StructuredTextEditor.java:3074)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.editor.PHPStructuredEditor.update(PHPStructuredEditor.java:3496)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.setModel(StructuredTextEditor.java:2971)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.doSetInput(StructuredTextEditor.java:1940)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.editor.PHPStructuredEditor.doSetInput(PHPStructuredEditor.java:2342)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3209)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow$1.run(ApplicationWindow.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow.run(ApplicationWindow.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2649)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3227)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3254)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.init(StructuredTextEditor.java:2595)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.editor.PHPStructuredEditor.init(PHPStructuredEditor.java:1200)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createSite(EditorManager.java:828)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1597)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2946)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2854)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2846)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2797)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2777)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2760)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.wizards.UntitledPHPDocumentWizard.performFinish(UntitledPHPDocumentWizard.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3562)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3186)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
    enter code here
```

any advice?

Comment: Ok.. 1) This is 3rd party software. 2) This has nothing to do with PHP. Those are (Eclipse!!!) Java errors 3) This is hardly a programming question. I would say it better fits on Super User, but then again: 3rd party software! - C'mon Mawg, with your reputation you should know this doesn't fit on SO :)

Comment: *How* did you install Eclipse? And what version?

Comment: Eclipse 4.8.1, installed through the "Ubuntu software" app

Comment: Well that can't be right. Eclipse.org itself has 4.6.1 as its latest Release version. http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ . Sounds like the Ubuntu package might have problems of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Ubuntu package is not properly built. Download the preassembled PHP IDE from eclipse.org: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/neonr and try it instead.